# Fill combobox from structure array

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I have a class as below :

`class villages
    {
        public string name;
        public int pId;
    }`

I use it in my form like this :

```
private villages[] centerVillage=new villages[]{
        new villages{name= "village1",pId=0},
        new villages{name= "village2",pId=1},
        new villages{name= "village3",pId=2},
        new villages{name= "village4",pId=3},
        new villages{name= "village5",pId=4},
        new villages{name= "village6",pId=5},
        new villages{name= "village7",pId=6},
    };
```

Now I want to fill my `combobox1` from `villages[]` that its `DisplayMember=name` and `valueMember=pId`

I already tried this but does not work.

```
combobox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(centerVillage, null);
combobox1.DisplayMember = "name";
combobox1.ValueMember = "pId";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the villages class you have to define properties to expose the values, it doesn't work with filed members:

```
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.ArgumentException:
    //     The specified property cannot be found on the object specified by the System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.DataSource
    //     property.
    public string ValueMember { get; set; }
```

This will fix the problem:

```
    class villages
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int pId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @user1592474 All you need to do is change your class to match his. The rest of your Code should just work. And change your comboBox1.DataSource to just centerVillage.

Comment: thanks i also implement it like this :              combobox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(centerVillage, null);                combobox1.DisplayMember = "name";
combobox1.ValueMember = "pId";

Comment: Like Mark said, you do not need a BindingSource for this, you can simply set the centerVillage array as DataSource

Answer (score 1):

```
combobox1.DataSource = villages;
combobox.DisplayMember = "name";
combobox1.ValueMember = "pId";
```